# Alternate for table.tpl.php

Tags: php, drupal, module, themes, filtering

Using ubercart marketplace, I don't want users to update their published products. 
On the user/id/selling view ubercart displays 2 links one to view the
product and one to edit the product. I wanted to remove the second link when 
the product is in published status (i.e. For Sale) I've written a table.tpl.php
that takes care of this.

```
<?php
 $args=arg();
 if (count($args)==3 && $args[0]="user" && $args[2]=="selling"){
  for($i=0;$i<count($rows);$i++){
  if (strcasecmp($rows[$i][4]['data'],"For Sale")==0){
    $pos=strpos($rows[$i][1]['data'],"</a><a");
    $rows[$i][1]['data']=substr($rows[$i][1]['data'],0,$pos)."</a>";
  }
  }
 }
 $output=theme_table($header, $rows, $attributes = array(), $caption = NULL);
 echo $output;
?>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing programmatically
from within a module, either by

1. curating the data before it gets to the view with some sort of hook.
2. doing the same thing I am doing with table.tpl.php but from a module so that I won't have to install that table.tpl.php file on a different theme (if it changes)